# Transfer data to database from datagridview

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

I need help with my data transfer. Whenever I try to transfer data from a selected datagridview row to a database, instead of transferring the selected row, it transfer all the data in the datagridview.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
    private void btnTransfer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblTransfered(deptNo,date,issuedFrom,scheduleNo,pvNo,name,amount,typeOfPayment) VALUES (@C1,@C2,@C3,@C4,@C5,@C6,@C7,@C8)", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@C1", SqlDbType.VarChar));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@C2", SqlDbType.VarChar));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@C3", SqlDbType.VarChar));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@C4", SqlDbType.VarChar));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@C5", SqlDbType.VarChar));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@C6", SqlDbType.VarChar));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@C7", SqlDbType.VarChar));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@C8", SqlDbType.VarChar));
            con.Open();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (!row.IsNewRow)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters["@C1"].Value = row.Cells[2].Value;
                    cmd.Parameters["@C2"].Value = row.Cells[0].Value;
                    cmd.Parameters["@C3"].Value = row.Cells[3].Value;
                    cmd.Parameters["@C4"].Value = row.Cells[4].Value;
                    cmd.Parameters["@C5"].Value = row.Cells[1].Value;
                    cmd.Parameters["@C6"].Value = row.Cells[5].Value;
                    cmd.Parameters["@C7"].Value = row.Cells[6].Value;
                    cmd.Parameters["@C8"].Value = row.Cells[7].Value;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Files Transfered for Approval Successflly");
        }
```

Comment: Well, yes, one would kind of *expect* that from a loop... What's your question?

Comment: my question is how do i make it transfer only the selected row data. thanks

Comment: Change dataGridView1.Rows -> dataGridView1.SelectedRows as simple as that

Comment: i tried that stil got the same issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert only selected row in `DataGridView` so you should loop on it, replace `foreach` line on this

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
```

**UPD**

MSDN:

"The SelectionMode property must be set to FullRowSelect or RowHeaderSelect for the SelectedRows property to be populated with selected rows."

Comment: when i change it to selectedRows, noting happens,. it just say transfer successful but noting in database table

Comment: @UmarE.Shaibu check `SelectionMode` property is set to `FullRowSelect` in `DataGridView`

Answer (score 0):

loop for `SelectedRows`

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
```